# measure of elements in $[0,1]$ bounded below has measure $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Define $E_N=\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) \geq N\}$

I claim $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} m(E_N)=0$ (or so I think this is true).

To show this can I start by obverting the $E_N$ are decreasing, that is for every $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

$$E_N \supset E_{N+1}.$$

And as $E_1 \subset [0,1]$ , by monotonicity $m(E_1)$ is finite since the unit interval has measure $1$. Then can I apply the monotone convergence for decreasing measurable sets? That is, do I have

$$m(\bigcap E_N) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} m(E_N).$$

If this holds I just need to show the intersection has measure $0$, correct? OR?

Comment: But what you are showing is that $m(E_N)\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$...

Comment: yes so sorry, typo just edited!

Comment: Then your proof is correct!

Comment: ah thanks! so the monotone convergence for decreasing is what I needed then!

Comment: But why would $\cap E_n$ have measure zero? Note that this set is where the function $f$ equals infinity. I think you need more hypotheses on $f(x)$ for this to be true.

Comment: So the intersection does not have measure zero? thus the limit of the measures cannot be zero either?

Comment: The function is only assumed to be measurable in the OP's question

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: It is assumed that $f$ is real-valued, not extended real-valued.

Comment: yes real valued, measurable function over compact.

Comment: @user251257 Ah huh, yeah it should be fine then. The function shouldnt equal infinity anywhere, so the intersection is the empty set, and has measure zero. Seems fine